# How to retain input values, after redirected in html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf, html, angularjs, js, and spring boot to create an web application. My main question is how would I be able to retain a input value and have that value display on the next page's input box?

Example: Stack overflow when you type a question in the top right search bar, you get redirected and you also get a new search bar that has the same values that you inputted previously.

[image: Here's the example]

**Index.html**

```
<form action="getDetails" method="POST">

    <p> Mac Address: </p><input type="text" name="inputMacAddress" id="inputMacAddress" required="required" placeholder="Enter Mac Address"  />

    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="marginButton"/> <input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="Redirect();" class="marginButton" />
    <script>
        function Redirect() {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.localhost:8080';
        }
    </script>

</form>
```

**getDetails.html**

```
<form action="getDetails" method="POST">

    <p> Mac Address: </p><input type="text" name="inputMacAddress" id="inputMacAddress" required="required" placeholder="Enter Mac Address"  />

    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="Redirect();" />
    <script>
        function Redirect() {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.localhost:8080';
        }
    </script>

</form>
```

Comment: You don't know PHP or you don't want to use it ?

Comment: Take a look into URL Query Parameters

Comment: @AymDev Don't want to use PHP.

Comment: URL query, cookie, localstorage, have the backend return it after the POST, use the angular routes... so many options. Also, SO probably doesn't reload the header, so that header doesn't actually change.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use Angular routes in your app? In your redirect (assuming you're redirecting from your angular code), you can add query parameters to your URL and use [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) to fetch them on your second page.

Comment: Can you give me a brief example with routeParams?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters using GET or POST. In most cases GET is used.
e.g. `http://localhost.html?q="Hello+world"`

And then pass that GET value to the input.

Take a look at `$routeParams` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)